# Restricted validity UK passport, Australian visa application

Tags: visas, australia, uk-citizens, passport-renewals

I am being given a restricted validity passport (in the UK) because I have lost too many passports. This means it will expire in a year. I am planning to travel to Australia in 7 months for a working holiday visa. Obviously the passport is gonna expire whilst I am there and I'll need to get a new 9 year one. Can anyone tell me if this will prevent me from getting the visa in any way? And advice on how to get around this?

Thanks x

Comment: Most countries require that a passport be valid for the duration of the visit. You would need to check with Australian immigration if this is the case here.

Comment: For a standard 10-year UK passport, you can renew it upto 9 months before it expires; the new passport will be valid for 10 years after the previous one was due to expire. If you renew more than 9 months early, only 9 months are added to the new passport. You may want to ask HMPO how this works for your passport. I'd imagine the worst that can happen is your new passport is also a 9-year one, without the 7 months remaining added to it.